# android java count down timer with background service

Tags: java, android, timer, background

I want to make a task which,

functions as a count-down timer

*which work on activity (show the count-down in the text field )

*and  background at the same time.

*Then  background service shows a notification after the count-down finished,

*not just that if the app is  closed and reopen, I want to show up the remaining time in the text field

what should I do, to achieve these four jobs

Answer (score 0):

Try to open a service on foreground method (background service cannot act well nowadays), it is up to you.
Your task counting info will save in (foreground) service
So when your app will reopen, your MainActivity will collect data from your service and display it in own TextBox.
For collecting data from service you can use BroadcastReceiver which starts within service.
You can show a notification from your service, it will be better if time count is end before app reopen.
You also can show notification from your activity if you ensure that user have to return your app before count down end.

I have not enough reputation for comment thats why i replied for answer.

Comment: thank you srabon , i tried to make the timer in the background so i can know the remaining second , and show it up in a notification , to be ensure the service is correctly works, if i close the app the count down in the notification stopped ,

Comment: and you said"or collecting data from service you can use BroadcastReceiver which starts within service." how can i do that.

Comment: Register separate BroadcastReceiver from both service and activity, communicate with each other with data by intent extra bundle. You can use LocalBroadcastReceiver.

Comment: and send broadcast every second?

Comment: You can send every second or just take current count when activity opening, then send that value to your count down task for counting from next, eg current value get 76, then count from 75

Comment: i will try , thank you srabon